# Angular 4.1: Can't open HTML selects on touch devices

Tags: html, css, angular

HTML select elements can't seem to open in my Angular app on touch devices (iOS, Android, whatever) no matter if the options are created problematically or are static. My selects contain no styling.

Google has proven unhelpful. Is there a HTML or CSS trick to getting my selects to work on touch devices that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Pure <select> does not work? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: is this a pure, native `<select>` element or are you using a UI library? Can you post your code and info about what you're using?

Comment: These are vanilla selects

Comment: Since I posted this question, I found out its not just my app but ANY vanilla select I find on the internet, including ones you can make in a w3schools sandbox. So the problem is probably our tablets.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that the best solution is to use a UI library that provides dropdowns that work in touch environments. We already use PrimeNG and it seems to work for this case.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Comment: I would not have posted this as an answer if I knew I'd get downvotes for it, sheesh. I was just saying what ended up working for me, since I did ask the question.